# c# Webbrowser Saving cache?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, web-scraping, webbrowser-control

Is C# Webbrowser keeping cache somewhere? And if so, how can I disable it?
All the information I found about the subject is from 2009 and outdated.

My problem is that the Webbrowser at somepoint stops loading new content while browsing back to the same website. Instead it's repeating what it had already shown. When restarting the windows forms app it is loading new content.

Thanks!

Comment: The server should tell the browser not to cache. Doesn't sound like a programming question. What have you tried?

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3421144/how-to-disable-caching-in-the-net-webbrowser-control or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1276619/caching-and-the-webbrowser-control-in-net help?

Comment: It sounds like what i'm looking for but the app crashes as soon as i try it

Comment: `but the app crashes as soon as i try it` As soon as you try **what**?

Comment: webBrowser1.Refresh(WebBrowserRefreshOption.Completely);

Comment: Can you show a screenshot of the app crashing when you run that line?

Comment: It looks ok after the refresh, then i try starting a thread and it stops responding

Comment: It crashes because the thread starts before the page finished loading, how can I check if the page is ready? I need something like this event listener    `private void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)`

Answer (score 0):

Using Application.Restart(); Solved my problem